# What is the earliest young adult dystopian trilogy?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Young Adult dystopian trilogies seem to be all the rage now, but what is the earliest novel trilogy that fits this formula?

I'm thinking along the lines of the Hunger Games (2008 -2010), Divergent Trilogy (2011-2013) (though there is a fourth book I would accept this) and the Maze Runner (2009-2011) (while this has five books, two are novellas, so I would also accept this).

The constraints I would put on this would be:

- post apocalyptic/future after an apocalypse
- young adult protagonists
- can be male or female
- the protagonist does not need to be "special" in some way.
- A trilogy of books (additional novellas, etc. won't exclude the series, if the trilogy itself is "self-contained")

The earliest I've found so far is Jean Ure's Plague Trilogy (Plague 99 (1989), Come Lucky April (1992) and Watchers at the Shrine (1994)).

Those were first published around 20 to 14 years before the Hunger Games. Is there anything known to be earlier?

Comment: Technically, there's more to the YA genre than having a YA protagonist (namely, certain themes are usually addressed). But I'm not sure how objective or well-defined it is.

Comment: The obvious one is *Gulliver's Travels* published in 1726.  Oh, then again, that is a quadrilogy, not a trilogy.

Comment: @Chenmunka I always thought of Gulliver as an Adult, rather than a Young Adult.  Also, it wasn't a post-apocalyptic world.

Comment: By "young adults" you mean what, persons aged 21-35, something like that?

Comment: Do you mean dystopia, or do you mean post-apocalyptic? The two genres tend to be paired but are in no way the same. (Eg 1984 is dystopia, but not post-apocalyptic)

Comment: @arcanistlupus I think both would be valid for my question. I see a lot of the novels have gone through an apocalypse and then becoming dystopian. In most cases the apocalypse is several hundred years before the setting of the novel

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Isn't *1984* also postapocalyptic? Didn't Ingsoc come to power in the aftermath of a nuclear war?

Comment: The Dune series was started in 65.

Comment: @user14111 ... "Young adult" fiction has a target readership of ages 12 to 18, and the protagonist(s) are generally within 2 years of that age range.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_adult_fiction

Comment: @Chenmunka Already the OP allowed to go beyond trilogies. Such distinctions always remind me of the Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy, which keeps being a trilogy

Answer (score 35):

There were two trilogies written by UK author [John Christopher](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/2001324.John_Christopher) that may count.

These are [The Tripods Trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/101942.The_Tripods_Trilogy) first published in 1967 and [The Sword of The Spirits trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_of_the_Spirits) first published in 1970.

Each is set about 100 years after an apocalypse (alien invasion, natural disaster), feature early/mid teen protagonists and there are 3 books in the main sequence although the Tripods has a prequel.

Comment: Nice answer, although I got the impression it was quite a bit more than 100 years in both cases.

Comment: That bio you've linked says "author of ... a stream of novels in the genre he pioneered, young adult dystopian fiction".

Comment: Yes, these sprang instantly to mind. +1. I still read them occasionally.

Comment: "Tripods" is a _great_ series-- highly recommend even for adult readers.

Answer (score 22):

There are surely quite a few.

The first that comes to mind is John Christopher's *Tripods* series, published in 1967-8. (There was also a prequel, but this was published much later in 1988 so the original trilogy should fit your criteria.)

Answer (score 8):

Mervyn Peake’s *Gormenghast* trilogy is set in a crumbling moribund society, and the protagonist of the first book, published in 1946, is seventeen years old.  There is also a side story published as a novella, but you said that is allowable.

Jane Gaskell’s *Atlan* series, from 1963,  is set in a collapsing dystopia and has a teenage girl as its protagonist.  Its themes are far more mature than the “Young Adult” genre of today (which it never was intended to be part of).  It could be considered a trilogy, insofar as some editions print *The Dragon* as the second part of *The Serpent*, there are two other books starring the original protagonist, and then there is one more book about her daughter.

Comment: Ghormenghast is about a stone fortress too big and timeworn to fathom and the weird humans that inhabit it. The civilians are remote villages of distrustful poor souls that scratch around to survive.

Comment: *Gormenghast* wasn't intended as a trilogy though.  Three books were just all Peake managed before he was unable to keep writing.  Supposedly, he envisioned as many as ten books total.

Comment: @Buzz Our loss, but—still counts.

Comment: Yeah, I agree (and upvoted), but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: I would not call Gormenghast YA, though.

Comment: @Lexible The contemporary YA genre is dissimilar to it in many ways, but the question asked for a trilogy with “young adult protagonists.”

Answer (score 2):

Charles R. Tanner's Tumithak stories (the first one is from 1932) immediately come to mind.

I don't think they're technically novels (although nobody can prove that they're *not*, I suppose), and there was a fourth story released in 2005, long after Tanner's death. Other than that, they meet your criteria.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please explain how they do, and in what ways they do not, match the requirements of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoyed Peter Dickinson's "The Changes" trilogy (1968-70) as a child and found it reasonably good as an adult a few years ago. It seems to fit your question in terms of being both post-apocalyptic and dystopian:

https://www.peterdickinson.com/books/weathermonger/

> In a Britain returned to a medieval way of life following the “Changes”, which turned people against machines and electricity, Geoffrey, the local Weathermonger (chosen for his ability to summon rain when the farmers need it) and his sister are about to be drowned as “witches” for breaking the rules and maintaining an outboard engine. Following a thrilling escape to France (which has been unaffected by the Changes which have gripped Britain), Geoffrey and Sally return on a mission to discover the source of The Changes. This was Peter’s first children’s book.

It was adapted into [a TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Changes_(TV_series))